# Is it possible to divide two columns using the the query builder?

Tags: database

Is it possible to divide two columns using the the query builder?

Like: `$query -> fields('A', array('valsA') / 'B', array('valsB'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex expressions you can use the [`addExpression()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7) method, e.g.

```
$query->addExpression('A.valsA / B.valsB', 'alias');
```